# Bluetooth, btmgmt tool how to set Link Mode

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I try to understand how  `btmgmt` work. I search command equal to:

```
sudo hciconfig -a hci0 lm master
```

I have try to use `sudo btmon` for dumping hci command but I have only this result:

```
@ RAW Open: hciconfig (privileged)  version...
```

with no op-code output, this not realy help me. Writing output to btsnoop format reveal some unknown op codes (`btmon -a /tmp/btsnoop`). With wireshark I have no HCI events, I don't understand.

Using `sudo strace hciconfig...` reveal socket and `ioctl call` with `ioctl(ctl, HCISETLINKMODE, dr)`

I read [HCISETLINKMODE value](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/bluetooth/hci_sock.h#L85) and [hciconfig function](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez/+/utils-2.3/tools/hciconfig.c#240)

but nothing about op-code to put the interface in `MASTER or SLAVE mode`. For some others btmgmt commands I use btmon output and the command op-code and I use op-code to search in [mgmt-api.txt](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/doc/mgmt-api.txt).

After reading that hciconfig would be deprecated, I'm trying to migrate commands using btmgmt and i just miss this one.

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: What is not working in your new code without this command? It might be easier for people to identify the fix for that rather than a direct translation of the command as there might not be a direct replacement. Alternatively, it might worth asking the question on the BlueZ slack channel: http://www.bluez.org/contact/

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for your reply. All work properly simply , by curiosity, I search to use `btmgmt` and learn about some api.